# Is it possible to obtain full path the objects find by a query

Tags: jsonata

Suppose you have `**[Colour = 'Purple']` query ([see here](http://try.jsonata.org/rk6KQiLhf)) and you wished to find actual path to the resulting nodes as below:

```
[
  Account.Order[0].Product[0].Description
  Account.Order[0].Product[3].Description
]
```

Is this possible? Any functions that can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could not find a way to do this either. Ended up using jsonpath: https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath